# SDL Optimization 8 problem with Google analytics in China region

Tags: experience-optimization

We want to implement SDL Optimization 8 with default integration with Google Analytics used for A/B testing (Experiment), But problem is we also  have a site which is working for China region where Google is blocked, So Can someone suggest how we should use SDL Optimization 8 for A/B testing (Experiment) use case.

Thanks
Piyush Jain

Comment: One thing you could do is lobby with the Chinese government and try to get them to unblock Google 

Comment: you may refer this post - https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-alternatives-to-Google-Analytics-in-China
I am not sure about the SDL Optimization 8 for A/B Testing

Comment: IIRC, you can create your own analytics provider... probably not a very simple task, but I remember it was designed so that you could plug in other analytics - and out of the box comes with GA.

Answer (score 2):

Unless things have changed since I last checked, Google Analytics is not blocked in China. It's one of the few Google services that are still usable.

That said, if things have changed and it *is* blocked -- you'll need to research alternative analytics engines and implement your own custom provider.

As Nuno rightly pointed out, we built a plugin mechanism that allows you to integrate with any analytics engine you want and still get the same functionality. Creating your own provider is fairly simple: you just extend the AnalyticsManager class and configure your class in the configuration file. Any complexity will likely come from the actual integration with your chosen engine.

Answer (score 0):

Google analytics is one of the only services from google that is not blocked. It will work most of the times but it can sometimes be slow to transfer data to google analytics. Lot of big chinese sites still use GA.